# .htaccess strange behaviour

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

If I put theese lines to `.htaccess` everything works well (when I'm going to `http://www.example.ru` I'm redirected to `http://example.ru`).

```
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Redirect all www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.ru/$1 [L,R]
```

But If I put exactly same lines to `<VirtualHost>` -> `<Directory>` section trying to go to `http://www.example.ru` redirects me to `http://example.ru/www`.

Anybody knows why?

**UPD**

New `VirtualHost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.ru
    ServerAlias www.example.ru
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/example/www/example.ru/www

    RewriteEngine On

    <Directory /home/example/www/example.ru>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /home/example/www/example.ru/log/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    SetEnvIf Remote_Addr 127.0.0.1 loopback

    CustomLog /home/example/www/example.ru/log/access.log combined env=!loopback

    # Redirect all www to non-www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.ru [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.ru$1 [L,R]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you following this direction for mod_rewrite in virtual hosts?  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#vhosts

Comment: It looks like I've been confused with `What is matched` section here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#regexp.

Comment: Can you post the whole (redacted) vhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent some time I've figured out, that in `VirtualHost` section, pattern will match against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string (in my case "/").

In Directory section, pattern will match against the filesystem path.